# WMS layer not shown over Google Map plugin layer in Leaflet application

Tags: leaflet

I have a simple Leaflet application containing 3 layers: OSM layer, Google Satellite layer (from Pavel Shramov plugin) and my own WMS layer.

My WMS layer show well over OSM basemap but when switching basemap to Google layer with layers control, Google Satellite layer show well but my WMS is not shown over it.
Exploring in Firebug tell me that my WMS images are there but not shown correctly OVER Google layer... This was working well using old version of Leaflet js/css but I want to use the new release 0.4.2...

Any idea how to patch this issue?

Thanks a lot

Etienne

Answer (score 0):

Finallly, adding this line:

$("#" + this._container.id).css("z-index", "auto");

in the _initContainer() function of the Google.js plugin solved the problem...

Check this conversation for more detail:  https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/issues/29

Regards

Etienne